# $AA^T=J_n-I_n$ has a solution over $\mathbb{F}_2$ iff $n$ is odd.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, solution-verification, finite-fields

I came across a combinatorics problem, which I turned into a Linear Algebra problem. In the end, it boiled down to the following problem:

\begin{align*}
 AA^T=J_n-I_n\pmod 2
\end{align*}
has a solution iff  $n$ is odd.

1. Here we are working over the field $\mathbb{F}_2$
2. $J_n$ denotes the matrix with all elements $1$.
3. $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix.

**My attempt:** If $n$ is odd, it is not hard to see that $A=J_n-I_n$ itself is a solution. I am not sure if my "proof" for the even $n$ part is correct. Throughout the rest of the solution we will be working over $\mathbb{F}_2$.
Let us denotes the $i$-th row vector of $A$ as $v_i$. Then the equation basically translates to
\begin{equation*}
v_i\cdot v_j=
\begin{cases}
0 & i=j \\
1 & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

For even $n$, $\det(J_n-I_n)=1\pmod 2$(see [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix)). Thus we conclude that $\det(A)=1\pmod 2\implies A$ is invertible $\implies$ $v_i$'s$(1\le i\le n)$ are linearly independent$\implies$ $v_i$'s form a basis pf $\mathbb{F}^n_2$. Now consider
\begin{equation}
v=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_iv_i\implies v^2= \sum \lambda_i^2v_i^2 + 2 \sum \lambda_i\lambda_j(v_i\cdot v_j )=0\pmod  2
\end{equation}
But this is a contradiction, because $e_1\cdot e_1=1$, here $e_1$ is the first standard basis vector of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$.

---

- This whole proof seems a little bit weak to me, in the sense there seems to be no *key observation/key step* in the proof.
- Also defining the dot product seems a bit iffy to me. After all, this does not make $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ into a inner product space.

Comment: Did you mean to restrict $A$ to be an $n\times n$ matrix? Otherwise, $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\1&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ is a solution when $n=2$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will edit my post.

Comment: Your proof seems fine. The "dot product" here is just a bilinear function to $\Bbb{F}_2$, having no connection with non-negativity since $\Bbb{F}_2$ is not even ordered.

Comment: @Zerox thanks for checking and thanks for the clarification.

Comment: FYI: This is Problem A4 from the [2011 Putnam Exam](https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2011.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are uncomfortable using dot products in your proof, I can provide a proof that does not use dot products.

First of all, the condition $AA^T=J_n-I_n$ implies that each row of $A$ has an even numbers of ones. To see this, note that the diagonal entries of $AA^T$ encode the parity of the number of ones in each row of $A$, while the diagonal entries of $J_n-I_n$ are zero.

Let $\newcommand{\one}{{\bf 1}}\one=[1\;\;1\;\cdots\;1]^\top$ be the $n\times 1$ column vector of all ones. The previous paragraph implies $A\one\equiv \vec 0$, so that $\newcommand{\rank}{\operatorname{rank}}\rank A\le n-1$, which further implies $\rank AA^T\le n-1$.

Now, assume $n$ is even. In this case, $\rank(J_n-I_n)=n$, since $J_n-I_n$ is its own inverse. This contradicts the previous paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

> This whole proof seems a little bit weak to me, in the sense there seems to be no key observation/key step in the proof.

For a different view, consider $G:=J_n-I_n$ as representing a skew symmetric bilinear form $V\times V \longrightarrow \mathbb F_2$ i.e. $g_{i,j}=\langle v_i, v_j\rangle$ where $\langle, \rangle$ denotes said form and $\big\{v_1,...,v_n\big\}$ provide a basis for $V$. Since we work over characteristic 2 we need to be careful and insist on defining skew-symmetry as isotropy, i.e. that $\langle v, v\rangle = 0$ for all $v\in V$.

With respect to OP's concern about a **key observation**, it is that $G$ implies a skew-symmetric bilinear form so all vectors are isotropic.  However the form is non-degenerate when $n$ is even, so the existence of a factorization $AA^T$ tells us that $G$ is *congruent to the identity matrix*, i.e. up to a change of basis our form is equivalent to the dot product *which is not an isotropic form* and this is impossible.

---

Mechanically, I'd write this as :

Assume $n$ is even and $AA^T = G = J_n-I_n$ exists.
The matrix determinant lemma tells us that $\det\big(J_n-I_n\big) = \det\big(I_n\big)\cdot (1+\mathbf 1_n^T\mathbf 1_n)=\det\big(I_n\big)\cdot (1+0) = 1$ thus the form is non-degenerate (which implies $\det\big(A\big)=1$).

Yet selecting $\mathbf x:= A^{-T}\mathbf e_k$ (with $\mathbf e_k$ being the kth standard basis vector)  gives
$1 = \mathbf x^TAA^T\mathbf x =  \mathbf x^TG\mathbf x=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n x_k\cdot x_j \cdot\langle v_k, v_j\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \langle x_k \cdot v_k,x_j \cdot v_j\rangle=  \big\langle\big( \sum_{k=1}^n x_k \cdot v_k\big),\big(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k \cdot v_j\big)\big\rangle=0$
Conclude $0=1$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Hi, I did not understand how you wrote $\det(J_n-I_n)=\det(I_n)(1+\mathbf{1}_n^{T}\mathbf{1})$.
Also is $A^{-T}=(A^{-1})^{T}$?

Comment: yes $A^{-T}=(A^{-1})^T =(A^T)^{-1}$.  Re: $\det\big(J_n-I_n\big)$: the ones matrix can be written, using the ones vector, as $J_n = \mathbf 1_n\mathbf 1_n^T$ so apply the *matrix determinant lemma* and see $\det\big(J_n -I_n\big)=\det\big( I_n + J_n\big)=\det\big(I_n + \mathbf 1_n\mathbf 1_n^T\big)$ $= \det\big(I_n\big)\cdot\big(1 + \mathbf 1_n^T I_n^{-1}\mathbf 1_n^T\big)= \det\big(I_n\big)\cdot\big(1 + \mathbf 1_n^T\mathbf 1_n^T\big)= 1 \cdot \big(1+0\big)=1$ since $\mathbf 1_n^T\mathbf 1_n = 0$ for even $n$ in characteristic two