symmetric bilinear map on a vector space over Z/2Z.
I need some support with the following two tasks
Task 1:
Let $K=\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$.
Show that $\forall \ \ n \in \mathbb{N}$ ($n$ even) there exist a non-degenerate, symmetric bilinear map
$b:K^n \times K^n \to K$ so that $b(x,x)=0 \ \ \forall x \in K^n$ and conclude why there can't exist an orthogonal basis.
I'm not sure, should I give one concrete bilinear map? If yes, than I would say the matrix with only $1$ entries on the antidiagonal and else 0 is such a bilinear map.
$$A= \left( \begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
0 & \ddots  & 1 & \vdots \\
\vdots & 1 & \ddots & 0 \\
1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right) $$
This matrix is also non-degenerate, because of $det(A) \neq 0$ because all rows are independent and
$$b(x,x)= \begin{pmatrix} x_1 & \cdots & x_n \end{pmatrix} A \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix} = x_nx_1+x_{n-1}x_2+ \cdots + x_2x_{n-1}+x_1x_n \ .$$
For $n$ even I used the fact, that $char(K)=2$. If $n$ would be odd, then each factor would not occur twice and the sum wouldn't vanish in general.
The next thing would be to argument why there can't exist an orthogonal basis.
I know a basis $B$ of $K^n$ is orthogonal $\Longleftrightarrow$ $A_B(b)$ is diagonal. So if I want to diagonalize the matrix A, than with every step of the process of the diagonalization, should all the entries vanish and we have at the end the zero matrix. Therefore it can't exist an orthogonal basis.
I know that this isn't a proof, it is more an assumption...
Am I right with my ideas? If not, I would appreciate any help how I can approach this task.
Task 2:
Show that for all symmetric bilinear map $s:K^n \times K^n \to K$ $\exists U \leqslant K^n$ with $\dim U = n-1$ such that $s(u,u)=0 \ \ \forall u  \ \in U$.
note: $K=\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$
For this task I don't have clue where to start. If you could give me a starting point, where I can work on, I would appreciate it.

What text are you using? For task 1, I would suggest considering the matrix of $J- I$ i.e. all ones except zeros on the diagonal and seeing my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4357005/aat-j-n-i-n-has-a-solution-over-mathbbf-2-iff-n-is-odd/ for why you can't have an orthogonal basis (i.e. $J-I$ can't be congruent to identity matrix in this case), though the argument at the end leading to $0=1$ works in general with small modification.

For Task 1: Yes, your $A$ is good, and your argument for its nondegeneracy is perfectly fine. ("Uneven" integers are called odd.) For the existence of an orthogonal basis, you're overthinking it. If there was an orthogonal basis, then what would happen if you compute an arbitrary $b\left(x,y\right)$ by expanding $x$ and $y$ in this basis?

For Task 2: I recommend writing $s\left(u,u\right)$ explicitly in terms of the coordinates of $u$, and seeing whether anything simplifies. Keep in mind that $K$ is not just some characteristic-$2$ field but literally $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$.

@user8675309 I just have handwriting notes from my professor and the tasks are from the blackboard, where he wrote them down.

@darijgrinberg if there would exist an orthogonal basis, then the Matrice $M_B(s)$ would have diagonal form. Atm for me, it is unclear if we are speaking about Basis of $K^n$ or $U$? And what do you mean by expanding $x,y$ in this Basis? Do you mean to write $x,y$ as linear combination of them?

In Task 2, you don't need an orthogonal basis. And I'm talking about $K^n$. And yes, linear combination.

I think I managed to solve it :). I will post it as a new answer of this post.

The word is "matrix", not "matrice".

I am sorry for all the typos, english isn't my first language. I am giving my best to improve it.

Task 1:
Assume there exist an orthogonal basis $B={v_1, \cdots ,  v_n}$.
Let $x \in K^n-${$0$}  s.t $x=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i v_i$ and $y=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \beta_i v_i$. Compute $s(x,y) \ \forall y \in K^n.$
$$s(x,y)= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_i \beta_j s(v_i,v_j) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i \beta_i s(v_i,v_i) = 0.$$ The last equation is true because of $s(v,v)=0 \ \ \ \forall v\in K^n$
But that means that $\langle x^{\perp} \rangle \subset Rad(s)$. Therefore $Rad(s) \neq $ {$0$}. But this is a contradiction to that $s$ is non-degenerate.
Task 2:
Let $(b_1, \cdots ,b_n)$ an basis of $K^n$ and arrange some of the basisvectors
$b_1, \cdots ,b_m$  s.t. it holds $s(v_i,v_i)=0$.
$\forall i=1,\cdots , m$ and $s(b_i,b_j) = 1 \ \ \ \forall j \in$ {$m+1,\cdots, n$}. For $m=n-1$ the proof would be done, so we have to work on the case $m<n-1$.
Define $c_j :=b_j + b_{j+1}$ for $j=m+1, \cdots , n-1$. It holds:
$$s(c_j,c_j)=s(b_j,b_j) + s(b_{j+1},b_{j+1}) = 0$$.
Note that {$b_1, \cdots , b_m , c_{m+1}, \cdots ,c_{n-1}$} are linear independent because of the construction of $c_j$. Therefore
$$U:=\langle b_1, \cdots , b_m , c_{m+1}, \cdots ,c_{n-1}  \rangle$$ and therefore $dim(U)=n-1$.
Because of bilinearity it holds $s(u,u)=0 \ \ \forall \in U$
